# How to access the URL parameter id in Coldfusion if it's after a hashtag #?

Tags: coldfusion, uri, fragment-identifier

After trying for about an hour without success... (`coldfusion8`) a dummy question, but I*m stuck:

My URL (Jquery Mobile, no pushstate, that's why it looks like it is):

```
 http://www.page.de/test/mem/search.cfm#/test/mem/search.cfm?id=9900000003869
```

If I output:

```
<cfdump output="e:\website\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#url#">
```

I get this:

```
catch - struct

ID: 9900000003869
```

But how do i access it... I'm trying forever, nothing works:

```
<cfdump output="e:\website\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#id#">
<cfdump output="e:\website\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#ID#">
<cfdump output="e:\website\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#url.id#">
<cfdump output="e:\website\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#url.ID#">
<cfdump output="e:\website\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#StructGetValue(url,"id")d#">
...
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I haven't had this problem in a while but now that I think of it, our CF server always ignored everything after the # in the url. Made it a pain to find the anchors in a url to the degree of using javaScript to assist.  Do you know how your cf or web server is set up not to ignore the address after the # signs?

Comment: The server cannot "see" the hash in the URL, nor should it. You should be passing everything after the `#` to the server via JavaScript and then getting the response back.

Comment: @ChrisPeters that has always been my experience too but it seems Frequent 'sees' everything past the hash, hence his cfdump has a result, GetQueryString() isn't null and <cfoutput>#url.id#</cfoutput> doesn't throw a 'not defined' error.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Regardless of what `GetQueryString()` returns, the purpose of hashes in URLs like that is so JavaScript can handle it. Twitter uses hash-bangs (`#!`) in their URLs so that JavaScript does the heavy lifting via AJAX.

Comment: right, that's understood. So no ideas then as to why his cf server isn't ignoring everything right of the hash per his example?

Comment: This isn't to do with the CF server - it is the client-side browser that doesn't (shouldn't) send the page fragment (the name for this segment; it's _not_ a hashtag). There is more going on here than has been described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... This works:

```
  URL = http://www.page.de/test/mem/search.cfm#/test/mem/search.cfm?id=9900000003869

  <cfset objRequest = GetPageContext().GetRequest() />
  <cfset strUrl = right( objRequest.GetRequestUrl().Append( "?" & objRequest.GetQueryString() ).ToString(), 13)>
```

[Credit](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/378-Getting-The-Requested-URL-From-The-Page-Request-Object-Servlet-Without-Using-CGI.htm)

If someone finds an easier, please post. I will check as answer.

Comment: what do you expect the "url variable" to contain?

Comment: I tried using testlink.cfm#/test/mem/search.cfm?id=9900000003869. When I output getRequestUrl() I get http://mydomain.com/testlink.cfm. I get null when I output getRequestUrl().  I also get nothing in my <cfdump var = "#url#"> if you were getting something in your dump as you indicated, using the correct syntax for isDefined("url.id") should have worked.

Comment: If `GetPageContext().GetRequest()` is returning the URL detailed above then the client software is broken and sending an incorrect URL to the server.

Comment: @ok. Valid point. Posting an issue to JQM, although it could also be my tampering with the navigation system. Anyway. Thanks for everybodys input

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read this from a txt file?

Can you not simply use:

```
<cfdump label="catch" var="#url.id#" />
```

Does that work?

**EDIT:**

Could you try capturing and formatting what you need first then after, writing it to the file?

For example, try using:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myFileContents">
<cfoutput>#url.id#</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cffile action="Write" file="e:\website\dump.txt" output="#myFileContents#" />
```

I have not tested this code, but give it a go and see!

Might want to put a check on that **URL** variable too using `isDefined()`

Good luck.

Comment: No, I'm dumping to file and not to screen. Sure I could dump to the screen. Does it make difference?

Comment: what do you mean "how do I access it"? the dump or just use the variable? <cfoutput>#url.id#</cfoutput>

Comment: @Travis. Ok. I can output the value, but if check `<cfif isDefined(url.id)>` it's false. That's the problem, the struct is defined and returns ID=9900000003869, but I can't test for it... killing me. I know if I remove the hashtag part of the URL it's working, so this is the problem, but I cannot temper with the URL, so I need another way to get. RIGHT() maybe?

Comment: the correct syntax for isDefined is <cfif isDefined("url.id")> (don't forget the quotes). you can also use structKeyExists for a more accurate answer <cfif structKeyExists(url, "id")>

Comment: More on that: isDefined(url.id) asks CF if a variable named 9900000003869 exists (the value of url.id) which it does not. you want to know if url.id exists so you need to put it in quotes isDefined("url.id")

Comment: @frequent I have updated my answer...see the edit. Does this help at all?

Comment: It is perfectly valid to output to a file with [cfdump](http://cfdocs.org/cfdump), and this has nothing to do with the question/problem.

Comment: @Peter: thanks. I'm always dumping to file, because on Jquery Mobile page, the dump is always under the content, so I have to remove the page content in order see my dumps, while on dump to file I can check all dumps comparing with what is displayed on the page. Just a habbit.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research on fragment identifiers (which is a new term to me :( )prompted by Peter and Duncan's comments, I've found from wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the
>   URI: namely, its processing is **exclusively client-side with no
>   participation from the server** — of course the server typically helps
>   to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the
>   processing of fragments. When an agent (such as a Web browser)
>   requests a resource from a Web server, **the agent sends the URI to
>   the server, but does not send the fragment**. Instead, the agent waits
>   for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the
>   resource according to the document type and fragment value.

now, being your client IS sending the fragment and the url variable is accessible to you for some reason, using it is done by my original post to follow.

```
<cfoutput>
```

is generally how you output a variable or other evaluations to the screen.

```
<cfset myName = "Travis">
<cfoutput>Hello, my name is #myName#</cfoutput>
```

You can also access the variable by using it in a statement that doesn't output anywhere.

```
<cfset myFullName = myName & " Mak">
```

You can also use the variables in a query

```
<cfquery name = "qSomeQuery" datasource = "#application.dsn#">
  select * from table where id = #url.id#
</cfquery>
```

However, that's the bad way to use it in a query, you should always use cfquery param.

```
<cfquery name = "qSomeQuery" datasource = "#application.dsn#">
  select * from table where id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.id#">
</cfquery>
```

The problem you're having in testing the variable is due to incorrect syntax.

`<cfif isDefined("url.id")>` verses `<cfif isDefined(url.id)>` a more accurate test is `<cfif structKeyExists(url, "id")>`

For some reason my CF server truncates everything in the url after the # but yours doesn't seem to have this problem.  As your cfdump states, you can see your url variables so "accessing" the url variable is as easy as using it:  `#url.id#` or testing it `<cfif isDefined("url.id")>`

Comment: I know how I can output to screen/file. My problem is I can*t access the parameter ID in the URL if it has hashtag `#` and the parameter is after the hashtag. If I ouput the url struct to screen/file, the parameter is there. But if try to test for existence it fails. Thats my problem.

Comment: well, your question is "how do I access a variable". What do you mean "in the URL if it has a hashtag"? give me an example. It sounds like you're asking the wrong question or you're having more than one problem.

Comment: This is the URL Jquery Mobile returns: `http://www.page.de/test/mem/search.cfm#/test/mem/search.cfm?id=9900000003869` and which I cannot alter without breaking the navigation. Try to extract the id. Not so easy as it looks (see my answer below).

Comment: the url variable as well as cgi.query_string contains everything after the '?'  the hash after.cfm has nothing to do with the url variables. if you want to test it, <cfoutput><cfif isDefined("url.id")>#url.id#</cfelse>url.id does not exist</cfif></cfoutput>

Comment: Your answer 'is not useful' in answering the question, which isn't about how to scope variables or use cfqueryparam, but how to access values in the URL hash.